# Convert swift to objective-c on react native project

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native

I want to convert bellow code to objective-c code:

```
import Foundation

@objcMembers
final class RNBridgeInstanceHolder : NSObject {
  
  static let sharedInstance = RNBridgeInstanceHolder()
  
  var bridge: RCTBridge?
  
  var rctRootView: RCTRootView?
}
```

**I tried like this header file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RNBridgeInstanceHolder: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTBridge *bridge;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RCTRootView *rootView;

@end
```

**main file below**

```
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import "RNBridgeInstanceHolder.h"
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation RNBridgeInstanceHolder : NSObject
  RCTBridge *bridge;
  RCTRootView *rootView;
@end
```

Anyone please help me to convert this code!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to convert swift code to objective c

Comment: What problem are you having in your attempt to translate the code? What do you need help with specifically regarding the translation? The code you posted is a start. Show the rest and explain what you need help with. But do keep in mind that you should delete the two global variables you added to the .m file. You probably intended to add two instance variables but they are global variable. Either way, they are unnecessary since you already have the properties defined in the .h. That just leaves adding the singleton. There are countless examples of that. Give it a try.